# Is it possible for foreigners for any reason to enter China?

Tags: international, covid-19, travel, china

Non Chinese citizens of any status including green card or permanent residence permit holders.

Can they enter mainland China if they live there but left to visit abroad given the current Corona virus restrictions?

Note this may be better suited to travel.SE, and if so then please feel free to migrate although it is more about returning to one's place of residence than it is about traveling away.

Comment: [Expats.SE] might be a better choice than [Travel.SE].

Comment: The title asks about visiting China, but the body talks about residents returning home - they might have different answers so could the OP clarify, please.

Comment: @Rick all done ..